# Accessing raspberry pi NAS with another raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cloud, samba, nas

I'm a mediocre raspberry pi enthusiast. I've been researching this for a while but can't find what I'm doing wrong.

I created an NAS server using a raspberry pi B + model using samba. I can access the server with my windows 10 computer, no problem.

However I'd like my other raspberry pi's to have access to the NAS server. I've gone to the network settings and attempted to connect to it, but I get 2 errors stacked on top of each other one says "SSH program unexpectedly exited" and the other says "the specified location is not mounted"

I've tried updating, upgrading, as well as installing ntfs-3g, the new pi client but nothing seems to be working.

is there another mounting procedure I can try?

Comment: How are you trying to do this? Are you using `mount -f cifs` or something like that?

Comment: Yeah I was trying to do it on boot, luckily I found this forum with my answer. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=52089

Answer (score 0):

By default raspberry, pis can't be clients try installing there's from the documentation.

```
sudo apt install samba samba-common-bin smbclient cifs-utils
```

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/samba.md